# How can I inject a real instance of EntityManager in Spring Boot unit tests?

Tags: spring-boot-test, hibernate-entitymanager

While attempting to use the EntityManager to get access to my Hibernate Metamodel, I realized that any time I tried the following, my unit test would get stuck on initialization. The test wouldn't spit out any error logs, but instead would continue to run without end.

```
@SpringBootTest
class Test {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;


}
```

Are you not able to inject a real instance of the EntityManager in Test classes? Is there a way to be able to inject this EntityManager?